# Import specific columns from CSV with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a CSV file with several million rows:

```
origin,destination,commute_time
A,B,123
C,D,234
...
```

I'd like to load this into a table in [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE commutes(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  origin VARCHAR(20),
  destination VARCHAR(20),
  time INT,
  distance FLOAT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Cloud SQL has a CSV import feature:

[image: Cloud SQL CSV Import]

Unfortunately, this assumes that the CSV file has no header row (it interprets the header row as data). It also assumes that the CSV file contains every column from first to last. So the `origin` column in the CSV file is interpreted as the `id` column in the table.

How can I import my data into this table? I'm using Cloud SQL v2 beta. Cloud SQL v1 had an [import API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/import) which let you specify a list of columns, but v2 does not have an API yet.

Comment: Am I wrong, but you post your question, and 1 second after the answer?

Comment: [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to reorder the columns in your table to match those in the CSV. In particular, you want to put columns like `id` (which are missing from your CSV) after the columns which are present.

So the table should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE commutes(
  origin VARCHAR(20),
  destination VARCHAR(20),
  time INT,
  distance FLOAT,
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

and the CSV should look like:

```
A,B,123
C,D,234
...
```

The [Cloud SQL V2 Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quickstart#connect_to_your_instance_using_the_mysql_client_in_the_cloud_shell) puts its example `id` column in the last position, so I assume this is a standard practice.

Comment: For the ones trying this on a Postgres 9.6 database on CloudSQL: this doesn't work.